# How to update the positional coordinates of my rect?

Tags: python, pygame, rect

I'm creating a memory card game, but having difficulty updating each boxes' rect starting positions. First `for` loop loads each image and the second get's the starting position for each one. When I do a collision test, it only answers to <0,125,0,175> as my rect position's aren't updating. How can I update this?

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

screen_height = 800
screen_width = 800
card_x_size = 125
card_y_size = 175
marginx = 45
marginy = 25

class Box():
    def __init__(self,image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect()

    def draw(self,screen):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

def play_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

    back_images = ['back.jpg']*16
    back_image_list = []
    for back_image in back_images:
        back_pic = pygame.image.load(back_image)
        back_pic = pygame.transform.scale(back_pic, (card_x_size,card_y_size))
        back_image_list.append(back_pic)
        rect = back_pic.get_rect()

    boxes = [Box(img) for img in back_image_list]


    for j, box in enumerate(boxes):
        pos_x = marginx + j % 4 * available_spacex
        pos_y = marginy + j // 4 * available_spacey
        box.rect.topleft = (pos_x, pos_y)
        print(pos_x,pos_y)


    while True:
        mouse_clicked = False
        clicked_card = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mouse_clicked = True
                print(mousex, mousey)
                if rect.collidepoint(mousex,mousey):
                    clicked_card = True
                    print("hit")

        for b in boxes:
            b.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()

play_game()
```

Comment: Guess my question is how would i put it in my first loop? the first loops through my string list elements and the second iterates over ints to get the position

Comment: i think i just need to update the rect positions so that when i do call a collision test, it's functioning the way i want. Just not sure how I get the positions from `box.rect.topleft`to update to the rect

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your current code contains many variables that are not defined and does not contain the `print(rect)` statement that you mention in the text of your question.

Comment: hey @Rabbid76 yes i've tried it, it's updating the rect positions now (thank you!) but now not drawing on the screen correctly nor is the collision test working. but thanks you've answered my main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to evaluate whether the mouse click is on one of the `box` objects:

```py
for box in boxes:
    if box.rect.collidepoint(mousex, mousey):
        clicked_card = True
        print("hit")
```

---

function `play_game`:

```py
def play_game():
    # [...]

    while True:
        mouse_clicked = False
        clicked_card = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
                mouse_clicked = True
                print(mousex, mousey)
                for box in boxes:
                    if box.rect.collidepoint(mousex, mousey):
                        clicked_card = True
                        print("hit")

        for b in boxes:
            b.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: @doulikepeaches So you did it wrong. Of course you've to set the positions before. You have to do this code after the 2nd loop.